# Using a MySQL Query result as a PHP variable

Tags: php, mysql

I am having an issue declaring a PHP variable as a MySQL result.

Code:

```
$num = mysql_query("SELECT num FROM numbers ORDER BY num DESC LIMIT 1");
```

What it does it retrieve the latest entry in the database, which is an int, and I want it to store into the PHP variable `$num`. Is this possible?

Comment: See the manual examples. [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/mysql_query) returns a result handle or something. You need to fetch a row or column.

Answer (score -1):

> Is this possible?

Yes, that is possible.

You should, however, use mysqli or PDO instead of the old mysql_ functions.

See: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

An example of how it could look:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT num FROM numbers ORDER BY num DESC LIMIT 1");
$num = $result->fetch_object()->num;
```